# Copy one array to another using Array.Copy(a, 0, b, 0, 20);

Tags: c#

If I click on btn1 the contains of array 1 (generate) will change. What I want to do is: after clicking on btn2 (Reset btn) want to copy the elements of array 2 (n) to array1 (generate) but I'm getting this error:
Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] generate = new string[20]   {"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7","Name8","Name9","Name10","Name11","Name12","Name13","Name14","Name15","Name16","Name17","Name18","Name19","Name20" };
        string[] n = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10", "Name11", "Name12", "Name13", "Name14", "Name15", "Name16", "Name17", "Name18", "Name19", "Name20" };

    string name;
    int Num;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // START btn
    {
        Num = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) - 1;
        if (Num < 20)
        {
            if (generate.Length > Num)
            {

                for (int i = Num; i >= 0; i--)
                {

                    name = generate.ElementAt(i);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(name); // Print it to list1 
                    generate = generate.Where(s => s != name).ToArray(); // Delete name after using
                }
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Sorry, remaining names =" + generate.Length);
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.AddRange(generate);

        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Max name is 20!");

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Reset btn
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        textBox1.Clear();
        Array.Copy(n, 0, generate, 0, 20);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please help if you could, I am new with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to duplicate array.

```
  var array2 =  array1.ToList().ToArray()
```

If you use `.Copy` method make sure your range is correct

Comment: +1, I was going to suggest: `string[] generate;
            generate = new string[n.Length];
            n.CopyTo(generate,0);`, but yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

When you click button 1, the following line is creating a new array for the generate variable which is of size less than 20:

```
generate = generate.Where(s => s != name).ToArray(); // Delete name
```

So, when you call button 2, you are trying to copy from array n of size 20 to the array `generate` of size less than 20.